# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException( 'Error getting value from 'Id' on 'Goodbuy.Models.product'.') when serializing a realm object to json

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm trying to serialize my realm object to a json string, but I'm getting **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:** 'Error getting value from 'Id' on 'Goodbuy.Models.product'.' Here is the method where the serialization happens:

```
    async void OnItemSelected(product item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var model = await ProductService.GetProduct(item.Id);
     
        //Convert Object to string 
        string jsonStrObj = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));

        // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
        
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?ProductModel={jsonStrObj}");


    }
```

below is my realm object class:

```
public class product :RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [MapTo("_id")]
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
    [MapTo("brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
   
    [MapTo("image_url")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    [MapTo("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
   
    
}
```

Comment: What is the value of id? Is this integer value or string?

Comment: The value is something like this, "_id":{"$oid":"600a87ccd2a5c05244d93f76"}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException (Error getting value from 'Value' on 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble) serializing SqlGeography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848550/newtonsoft-json-jsonserializationexception-error-getting-value-from-value-on)

Comment: Please change it to string and then try

Comment: I can't change it to string because I'm using mondoDb realm sync, so it wont sync my data anymore

Comment: @PHULUSOGOVERNRAMULIFHO this will definitely help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JsonObject attribute with MemberSerialization.OptIn argument, and creating custom converter that just spits out the Guid portion of the ObjectId Json.NET how to serialize an ObjectId.

```
 [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class product : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
   
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
  
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

   
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "image_url")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


}

 [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class product : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
   
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
  
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

   
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "image_url")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


}
```